# Flutter how to accesss a single SharedPreference instance through the whole app

Tags: flutter

I'm using SharedPreferences to store settings data, problem is that I need to access this data in multiple different locations & right now I need a new futurebuilder for every different screen I need to access the data from..

Is there anyway to only get SharedPreference data ONCE & then access that instance throughout the app instead of  having a bunch of futurebuilders everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file called `globals.dart` and create a `SharedPreferences` variable without setting it:

*globals.dart*

```dart
SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;
```

Then, in your `main.dart` instantiate your varaible `sharedPreferences` within your `main()` function:

*main.dart*

```dart
import './globals.dart';

void main() async {
  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Now you can call your global variable `sharedPreferences` in *any* file throughout your project as long as you import `globals.dart`:

```dart
sharedPreferences?.setString('key', 'value');
```

Comment: so in this case  it's better to do `late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;` and you don't have to use `!` each time you want to access it